# Apparent power meaning

Tags: power, power-electronics

As far as i have read v(rms) is a dc value and i(rms) is also a dc value and apparent power is multiplication of both of them.so,can apparent power be represented as dc power absorbed by an ac circuit.am i guessing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are considering any AC circuit, Power depends upon the phase difference(let's say it 'phi') between resistive & reactive components.
For DC you have studied P = V * I

But for AC power dissipated is given by P = e * i *cos(phi). 
cos(phi) is called as power factor which decides how much power is actually dissipated.It depends upon the reactive(|XL-XC) & resistive() component of the circuit. Go through the link for how to find 
[phase difference or power factor](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/series-circuit.html).

since L(in the form of magnetic field) & C(in the form of electrical energy) are energy storing components. product of V & I will give you the apparent power but some fraction of energy will be stored in reactive components(L & C).Hence actual power dissipated will always be less than the apparent power.

[image]

more about [Apparent power](http://www.electrical4u.com/electrical-power-factor/)

Comment: That's good enough for me, I'd just add that apparent power is used for cable sizing.

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about power being

*P=* V*I

here *V* and *I*, they both are vector/phasor quantities, so you can not take there magnitudes to calculate the apparent power, their angles from a reference matters.Taking the magnitude will yield you wrong results.